# Convert the uploaded files to jar or rpm files

Tags: php

I need to upload several files and stored it as packages in php.

While storing the packages, it have to be in .jar or .rpm format as output.

Is there a way to convert the package files to .jar or .rpm on fly or need to work on system commands. Is this OS dependent.

Any Help!

Answer (score 1):

A .jar file is basically a zip archive so you should have no problem generating one in php.

Comment: No it's not. A JAR file has a different specification than a ZIP file.

Comment: The actual format is zip, the only thing which makes a zip file to a jar is the META-INF folder.

Comment: Thanks, i created jar file with META-INF. you have any idea to convert it to EPM format.